# Kill MapReduce job if driver program crashes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a driver program that launches a MapReduce job with org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(boolean) on Hadoop 2.4.0. The problem I have is if the driver program crashes in the middle of the job, the job will continue running. Is there a way to kill the launched MapReduce job if the driver program crashes? Whether or not the driver program crashes is not something under my control. I'm guessing that it would require the client and job to periodically poll each other. Is there a setting or method in the API for this?

Comment: Try jobClient.run(conf). This will throw an exception if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your applicationId (jobId) listed in the yarn webUI or you can type `yarn application -list` in the yarn resource manager node of the cluster. You can kill that applicationId by using `kill` command as: `yarn application -kill <applicationId>`. I guess this will solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a better solution to kill map reduce job automatically as soon as driver process is killed suppose using SIGKILL?